# REGEX_REPLACE not matching all chars from the beginning to the first occurrence of a 5 digits word

Tags: mysql, regex

I've this record in a Mysql table:

```
ADDRESS
----------------------------------
sdasd 4354 ciao 12345 sdsdsa asfds
```

I would like to match all chars from the beginning to the first occurrence of a 5 digits word, including it.
In this case, using REGEXP_REPLACE, I would like to remove the substring matched and return `sdsdsa asfds`.

What I've tried to do is this:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(ADDRESS, '^.+\b\d{5}\b.','') FROM `mytable`
```

The regexp seems to work testing it in this [snippet](https://regex101.com/r/7khxKO/1/) and I cannot understand why Mysql won't.

Comment: You need `REGEXP_REPLACE(ADDRESS, '^.*?\\b\\d{5}\\b\\s*', '')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MySQL supports POSIX regex](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html) which doesn't support PERL like properties e.g. `\b`, `\d` etc.

This regex should work for you:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE
('sdasd 4354 ciao 12345 sdsdsa asfds', '^.+[[:<:]][0-9]{5}[[:blank:]]+', '') as val;
```

```
+--------------+
| val          |
+--------------+
| sdsdsa asfds |
+--------------+
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `^.+`: Match 1 or more of any characters at the start (greedy)
- `[[:<:]]`: Match a word boundary (zero width)
- `[0-9]{5}`: Match exactly 5 digits
- `[[:blank:]]+`: Match 1 or more of whitespaces (tab or space)

Comment: I think MySQL 8.0 does handle the `\` variants.  But, depending on the client, you may need to double up the backslashes.

Comment: Yes I have also realized today that newer MySQL versions support `\b` and `\d` though it might not be portable. Documentation says: `The Spencer library supports word-beginning and word-end boundary markers ([[:<:]] and [[:>:]] notation). ICU does not. For ICU, you can use \b to match word boundaries; double the backslash`

Comment: @anubhava, Thank you for sharing nice command sir. May I ask you how are you running this, is it usual mysql client or any regex site we have for this?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I test using local MySQL setup I have installed